# font_add_google function from showtext/sysfont packages not working

Tags: r, fonts

I am trying to get a font from *google font* but `font_add_google` fails:

```
> library(showtext)
Loading required package: showtextdb
> font_add_google("Staatliches","Staat")
Error in search_db(name, db_cache, handle) : font not found
```

The font exists on google [font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Staatliches?selection.family=Staatliches) but when I tried to check:

```
library(tidyverse)
> font_info_google(db_cache= FALSE) %>%  filter(family == "Staatliches")
[1] family       category     num_variants variants     num_subsets  subsets      version      lastModified
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Does it show up when you call `sysfonts::font_families_google()`? The fonts database isn't always up to date. Also, not every font on Google is available to download because of licensing issues; see [github issues](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/14)

Comment: @camille It is not in the list *but* the font does have an open font license attached to it. Guess I can always use another font. I'll just add a comment on the issue raised on github.

Comment: In recent versions of `sysfonts`, the parameter `font_add_google(db_cache = FALSE)` will directly fetch the font database from Google and hence is always up to date.

Comment: @yixuan your comment is quite useful. I've been struggling to add font that are available on google fonts website but failed. but with setting that `db_cache` to `FALSE` solved my issues. thanks  a lot!